# SQL Server - improving query speed using multiple servers - your thoughts/advice/experience

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing

I was hoping to get some advice on improving speed of queries by sharing a query across multiple SQL Servers. I have done some research but cannot see a readily available solution.

I have a situation where I am potentially storing hundreds of thousands of rows with huge text columns (several thousand characters). I want to do a wildcard search of the text columns. In testing the query it can potentially take several seconds to return the results.

My questions are:

- Does SQL Server have any built in functionality that would allow me to cluster the servers so that I can spread the query over multiple servers and thus reduce the time for the query?
- If you were in my position what approach would you take?
- What are your thoughts on this? What kinds of issues would I get and what would your advice be?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure SQL Server is the right tool for the job here. Adding read-only replicas is like masking the problem by just adding hardware. If you have the appetite, look into something like Elasticsearch.

Comment: Always On Availability Groups isn't a solution in this case. I don't know any solution that would resolve your first question. You should consider using Full-Text Search (Full-Text Search in SQL Server and Azure SQL Database lets users and applications run full-text queries against character-based data in SQL Server tables). It sounds like to be appropriate in your case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you. I will look at Full-Text search. My current testing I was just using a LIKE query. I wasn't aware of the performance comparrison

Answer (score 0):

> I have done some research but cannot see a readily available solution.

Ah.... you overlooked the elephant in the room, so to say.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017

SQL Server Always On Availability Groups can have read enabled secondaries. Guess what - they are exactly for this use case. You overlooked them in your research?

Now, that this is out of the job - and answers the fist of your 3 questions - we have not enough information to give a sensible answer for the rest.

Comment: Thank you but this wont speed up the search since the whole operation would still be run on a single server. A single search that would take 4 seconds on a standard setup would still take 4 seconds with a read only secondary. I'm looking for an off the shelf solution that would allow one server to search half the table and the other server to search the second half or something along those lines. I appreciate I could specifically code a program to query two servers with half each server only checking half but I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Yes, except you could run multiple in parallel. But yes, one query would not - manual sharding is the only solution. You wlikely will have to go big data for that. THis isa real edge case - not sying you are wrong, it just is a VERY rare requirement with a LOT of technical issues. Oracle IIRC can do that to a degree. Microsoft never went "cluster" like that.